# MySQL: Combining all results from a LOOP (possibly with UNION?)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

**EDIT: already solved and answered: but feel free to read along and see how the process went if you have similar questions**

**BACKGROUND**
I created a procedure called 'sea_dew_potion' and placed it within a loop called 'loopseadew'. the loop works as intended.

**QUESTION**
My loop produced 18 results, but I would like it to be in a single result set so I can export it to tableau to make a line graph with multiple data points to make some form of curve. After some research I think a `UNION` would work but I'm not sure how to go about it, mostly cause I just figured out how loops work and then how to fit another procedure within a loop haha. Thanks for the help!

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE loopseadew(IN p_base_name VARCHAR(255), IN p_base_amount integer, IN p_ing_name VARCHAR(255), p_ing_amount integer, p_pot_units INTEGER(3))
BEGIN
    DECLARE p_ing_amount int;
    
    SET p_ing_amount = 0;
    
    loop1: LOOP
        SET p_ing_amount = p_ing_amount + 1;
        CALL sea_dew_potion('sea dew', 100, 'skadite', 0, 10);
        IF p_ing_amount = 18 THEN
            LEAVE loop1;
        END IF;
    END LOOP loop1;
    SELECT p_base_name, p_base_amount, p_ing_name, p_ing_amount,
        m.price * p_ing_amount AS cost
    FROM
        multiplier m
    WHERE
        m.ing_name = p_ing_name;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT**: im getting some progress, but i am getting null values for columns 'heal' and 'cost'. values for heal is produced the procedure "sea_dew_potion". Right now i get 18 individual results with all the correct values, and one result with all the results combined but null values for heal and cost.
Screenshots at the bottom to show the problem between the result sets.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE allloopseadew(IN p_base_name VARCHAR(255), IN p_base_amount integer, IN p_ing_name VARCHAR(255), p_ing_amount integer, p_pot_units INTEGER(3))
BEGIN
    DECLARE x int;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE allresults (p_base_name varchar(255), p_base_amount int(3), p_ing_name VARCHAR(255), p_ing_amount int(3), heal decimal(10,2), cost decimal(10,2));
    
    SET x = 0;
   
    loop1: LOOP
        SET x = x + 1;
        CALL sea_dew_potion('sea dew', 100, 'skadite', x, 10);
        IF x = 18 THEN
            LEAVE loop1;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO allresults
        VALUES(p_base_name, p_base_amount, p_ing_name , x, heal, cost);
    END LOOP loop1;
    SELECT p_base_name, p_base_amount, p_ing_name, p_ing_amount,
        m.price * p_ing_amount AS cost
    FROM
        multiplier m
    WHERE
        m.ing_name = p_ing_name;
    SELECT * FROM allresults;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT PART 2**
Shout out to @blabla_bingo i finally got it! Here is the final query for anyone interested haha

```
CREATE PROCEDURE allloopseadew(IN p_base_name VARCHAR(255), IN p_base_amount integer, IN p_ing_name VARCHAR(255), p_ing_amount integer, p_pot_units INTEGER(3))
BEGIN
    DECLARE x decimal(10,3);
    DECLARE v_heal decimal(10,3);
    DECLARE v_cost decimal(10,3);
    DECLaRE v_total_amount int(3);
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE allresults (p_base_name varchar(255), p_base_amount int(3), p_ing_name VARCHAR(255), p_ing_amount int(3), heal decimal(10,2), cost decimal(10,2));
    
    SET x = 0;
   
    loop1: LOOP
        SET x = x + 1;
        SET v_total_amount = 
            (SELECT p_base_amount + x);
        SET v_heal = 
            (SELECT 
                round(max((2*(2.1*(p_base_amount/v_total_amount))*1*(1+sqrt(x/v_total_amount)*m.multiplier_value)*p_pot_units)),3)
            FROM
                multiplier m
            WHERE
                m.ing_name = p_ing_name);
        SET v_cost = 
            (SELECT 
                m.price * x
            FROM
                multiplier m
            WHERE
                m.ing_name = p_ing_name);
        CALL sea_dew_potion('sea dew', 100, 'skadite', x, 10);
        IF x = 18 THEN
            LEAVE loop1;
        END IF;
        
        INSERT INTO allresults
        VALUES(p_base_name, p_base_amount, p_ing_name, x, v_heal, v_cost);
    END LOOP loop1;
    SELECT p_base_name, p_base_amount, p_ing_name, p_ing_amount,
        m.price * p_ing_amount AS cost
    FROM
        multiplier m
    WHERE
        m.ing_name = p_ing_name;
    SELECT * FROM allresults;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[all results with no heal or cost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeTsP.png)

[individual result with heal and cost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeXBl.png)

[Final correct result with query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbNDN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION` has its drawbacks such as being unable to sort out using `ORDER BY` clause. Besides, a total of 17 `UNION` need to be used in this case if you decides to go along, which makes the query drag on too much. I would suggest use a result table and have your procedure `sea_dew_potion` insert into it. Then you can query the result table and probably make some adjustment before exporting into your `tableau` table. Finally,as a side note, instead of calling the `sea_dew_potion` 18 times in a loop,  we can also add a count parameter for the procedure `sea_dew_potion` ,so that we only need to define the count number and run the procedure once. e.g `sea_dew_potion(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,count_num int)`.

Comment: so i just edited my question with some updated code before i saw this comment. would you suggest in the temp result table 'allresults' i made, when i say `VALUES` i put the procedure name `sea_dew_potion` in it?

Comment: Also your count parameter sounds interesting, but i dont want to adjust the procedure in itself, as in i want to retain the ability to just get a single result when i call the procedure for specific variables but also use this new loop procedure just to obtain multiple data points to create a table to show that although potion A can heal a player more than potion B, it might not be worth it because of cost outweighing the benefit with a heal-to-cost ratio

Comment: The `INSERT INTO allresults
        VALUES(p_base_name, p_base_amount, p_ing_name , x, heal, cost);` query is to blame, in which you have yet to define the `heal` and `cost` variables. Use declare statements ,or put them into your parameter list for the procedure . Make sure you have the valid variables before using them in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: By the way , as your table `allresults`  already has column names `heal` and `cost`, please use other variable names to avoid confusion. e.g We can use user variables such as `@heal` and `@cost` in the value list of  `insert` statement. Make sure you define those user variables first .

Comment: you're the best thank you for all the help! Check out the edit part 2 if youre interested with how it finally came out

Comment: That's cool. Glad to be helpful.